# Using Push Notification to refresh page

Tags: javascript, websocket, web-applications, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a web app similar to UberEats. For the restaurant portal, I want to append incoming new orders on the dashboard so that the restaurant user can see orders coming in.

My idea is to use FCM push notifications to detect any new orders.

The following is my js code for receiving the payload from FCM. How do I add my own logic so that I can append the new order / refresh the dashboard to show the latest orders?

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  
  messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
      console.log(
          "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
          payload,
      );
      // Customize notification here
      const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
      const notificationOptions = {
          body: "Background Message body.",
          icon: "/itwonders-web-logo.png",
      };
  
      return self.registration.showNotification(
          notificationTitle,
          notificationOptions,
      );
  });
```

Comment: What is PHP part in this question?

Comment: Edited for more clarity